# Unsupported classversion when deploying to jboss

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jersey

I am trying to add jersey to our (old) jboss project but I get "Unsupported classversion" when deploying to jboss - which points to a compile vs runtime version mismatch. In production and on our test servers, the application runs on java 6 but it is built using java 7. Corporate bureaucracy means that it will take months to upgrade the servers to java 7 but the code itself no longer compiles in java 6 due to some javaws dependencies. So for the foreseeable future, I am stuck with these versions.

All my changes work fine if they are compiled and run in java 7 but don't deploy if compiled in java 7 but run in java 6.

I have tried using the maven-compiler-plugin to force the target to be 1.6 but then I run into "source release 1.7 requires target release 1.7" errors.

I can see that at least one the jersey jar artifacts that is downloaded by maven is compiled with java 7 (51.0) and that presumably is the cause. Anyone have any tips as to how I can go forward with this?

Comment: Downgrade your development machines to Java 1.6 until you're ready to upgrade to Java 7 in production.

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't clear. I can't deploy these changes to a server that is running under java 6 - that is my problem!

Comment: you are correct, you can't deploy 1.7 class files to a 1.6 jvm.  what is your question?

Comment: Well I'd like to use jersey despite these restrictions

Comment: If I understand you correclty, the problem is in the jersey jars. Then download a version of jersey that's compiled for Java 6.

Comment: Or if you really need the latest jersey version, download the sources (check the license to see what you can do) adn try to compile them for Java 6, modifying the code that isn't supported by that version.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, Downgrading the version of jersey to one compiled with java6 sorted the issue (kinda - I get some jersey problems now instead).

I extracted the class files from the .jar and ran "file" on one and I found that 2.6 version of jersey was the last to support java 6